# Symfony 2: Abstracting data input in order to allow many controllers, one model

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently banging my head against the wall trying to find a decent architecture for a system, but i guess i need some help from the Symfony experts here. I'm building a very simple application with two interfaces: normal web app (HTML forms, etc.) and a RESTful API. The two are not the same, but they share a lot of CRUD operations.

I have two Bundles, each one contains Controllers specific to each interface. One creates and validates forms using the Form component, another just parses data from the Request in whatever format it was sent (JSON or XML). However, this sucks. There's a lot of shared code between those two interfaces, such as parameter binding and validation. Although the model is the same, the way i receive the data from the user and interact with the model is pure anti-DRY.

Is there a way of bringing input binding and validation into a single, abstracted, operation? I started by creating a class that received the Request object from each controller, validated each parameter and communicated with the model. It worked great for the API, but i completely lost the Form component advantages.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using 2 different routes for each action but going to the same actual action

```
blah_blah.blahbadeblah:
    pattern: /blah/
    defaults:
        _controller: "BlahBlahBundle:Blah:index"
        json: false

blah_blah.blahbadeblah_json:
    pattern: /json/blah/
    defaults:
        _controller: "BlahBlahBundle:Blah:index"
        json: true
```

And then you could do a check at the end of the controller for `json` and then either respond with the full template or the JsonResponse containing the minimal stuff.

Comment: I'm already doing that. I'm not really discussing the I/O differences of the web controller and the API controller, but how to abstract the repeated code inside their actions that's related to Model interaction (data binding, data validation, etc).

Comment: What are the contents of your actual Controller?

Comment: For the web controller: instantiation of the entity, the form builder, form validation entity manager persiting, etc. For the API controller: input validation, entity instantiation, entity manager persisting, etc.

Comment: Could you edit your question and place the actual code in there.. would make a lot more sense then. I probably won't be able to help but at least then I would understand.